# How to add a value in dataframe columns with multiple excel sheets?

Tags: python, pandas

This should be an easy question!! But I'm stuck in it. Hope someone can help me, thanks!

SO I have 3 columns in 2 sheets (Ya, I just simplified to 2 sheets here). The dataset is in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qxGNShfrOgGXUfJd5t8qg2RoYDIcgNM9/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103815541757228048284&rtpof=true&sd=true

How to add a value in multiple dataframe sheets, then append it in a new dataframe with still 2 sheets?

```
ddf = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(40):
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, i)
```

For example,

```py
for i in range(len(df["first"]):
    df["first"].iloc[i] + 4
    df["second"].iloc[i] + 8
```

But it is just in one sheet, I need to do the same thing in 40 sheets.

p.s. Each sheets have same column and same index length

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "How to multiply dataframe columns with a value in multiple sheets?" Which sheets? And which columns from those sheets? If I understand correctly, there are three elements to this question: (1) multiply each sheet by columns from other sheets; (2) multiply each column by a constant; (3) export every DataFrame to one excel as a sheet. Pls confirm

Comment: Why are you reading the xcel in the dataframe, use openpyxl

Comment: @fishmulch Thanks for reminding me. BTW, I correct my question, and let's say "add" a value not "multiply", maybe easier to think about. 
It's the second one --multiply each column by a constant

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Is it quicker to read the data? Or...?

Comment: You just need to add some value to a column right?
you can loop through the cells and add it and rewrite back

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Yah, but after I did that, it return a list. I need to append it to a new dataframe, not a list

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I put my dataset above.

Comment: check @IMB's answer, I think that ll help you, can you  try that and let us know if that helps

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Thanks for that. But after it turns out to a dictionary, I don't know how to add a value in the next step. 

Comment: I can't understand.... Sorry

Comment: @Megan if I understand correctly, you want to add some constant to the column in one sheet, then concat the sheet data to the next sheet, and then to the third sheet, and then from third to the fourth and so on? right? So 40th sheet will contain data from all 39 sheet, right?

Comment: yah, seems right

Answer (score 0):

To read the whole worksheets from an excel you have to play with the sheet_name parameter of pandas.read_excel.

As you can observe in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) as default will be 0, so it will read only the first sheet.

As solution for your problem you should initialize this parameter as None to read all of the sheets and then loop over them.

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)
```

Then you can just loop for the dictionary of sheets that it gives you and make the addition of number that you want:

```
for df in dfs.items():
    for i in range(len(df):
        df.iloc[i] + 4
```

EDIT:
For dividing two columns:

```
for df in dfs.items():
    df['result'] = df['Bcolumn']/df['Acolumn']
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! But Sorry I am bad at this. So this turns out a dictionary, then what's the next step to add a value?

Comment: Thanks, may I ask an little bit extended question?

Comment: How to do if I don't want to add for a constant number. I want to add a number which is ```dfs["Bcolumn"]/["Acolumn"]```. Because it occurred an error said ```'dict' object has no attribute 'iloc'```

Comment: You will have yo search for that columns but in each dataframe not in the dictionary of dataframes. I will edit the answer with it.

Comment: Thanks for it. But it occurred an error of ```tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: Can you add the excel to the question in order to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

Trying an answer because I think I understand. Hopefully this helps.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for i in range(40):
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, i)
    df['first'] += 2 # constant of your choice
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)

writer.save()
```

If you want to loop through multiple columns and constants:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for i in range(40):
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, i)
    for col, val in zip(['first', 'second'], [10, 5]):
        df[col] += val
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I think you are almost right. But I just need to Add value to one column, not all dataframe. Thus, the type of data is not the same.

Comment: Gotcha, will edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope it could work 

Comment: Any luck? Please accept if this worked for you.

Comment: Not really, I am still figuring this out.

Comment: Actually, I found I gave too little clue and data. It' harder than I thought